# Server to AutoPull when someone pushes

Tags: github, github-actions, git-pull

So everytime one of the developers makes a git push, i want my remote server to automatically make a git pull. I have tried GitHooks/GitActions but nothing seems to work. Is this even doable with GitHooks/GitActions?

I already have a solution with a bash file that makes an hourly pull server side, but i wanted to have it only when someone pushes.